# Submiting form and transform model to match backend

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

I have different model in frontend and backend. When I submit form in frontend I need to transform that object to match backend model. Is there a better way than this one:

```
submit(confirmed: boolean) {
    this.transformCreditCardModel(confirmed);
    this.dialogRef.close({
      success: confirmed,
      productAdjustment: confirmed === true ? this.exposuresForm.value : null
    });
  }

  private transformCreditCardModel(confirmed: boolean) {
    const product = this.exposuresForm.value;
    if (confirmed && product.hasOwnProperty(ExposuresFieldNamesEnum.creditCardProductIdentification)) {
      const prefix = product.creditCardProductIdentification.accountPrefix;
      const number = product.creditCardProductIdentification.accountNumber;
      delete product.creditCardProductIdentification.accountNumber;
      delete product.creditCardProductIdentification.accountPrefix;
      product.creditCardProductIdentification.cardNumber = prefix + this.CREDIT_CARD_MASK + number;
    }
  }
```

I don't like the part where I am asking whether the object contain some property if yes then creating new one and deleting old one. Is there a nicer way to do this ?